# Insert multiple rows into multiple tables using SP in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, bulkinsert

How to send data to a stored procedure which is to be inserted as multiple rows in  multiple tables in MySql. i know the option load datafile and load xml. But i want to pass the data as a parameter to SP(dont want to use a file becuase i want to avoid file transfer from remote machine to server).

For eg. if i want to insert 2 rows to 2 tables how to send the data for all the 4 rows.

May be i can send 2 text params each one containing insert queries for each table. is it the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can send data as parameter,
Say you can have Text datatype parameter and you can send data with coma separated.
In SP you can extract data from the parameter and use it to insert into table

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myInsert; //
CREATE PROCEDURE myInsert(IN name1 CHAR(40), IN val1 INTEGER(11), IN name2(CHAR(40), IN val2 INTEGER(11))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test1 (name, val) VALUES (name1, val1), (name2, val2);
INSERT INTO test2 (val) VALUES (val1), (val2);
END; //
```